# Is that mandatory to add the [SecurityPermission()] attribute to override the WndProc method?

Tags: c#, winforms, wndproc

I have creating the custom control by overriding the System.Windows.Forms.Control.
Now i have to override the **CreateParams** and the **WndProc** for my customization.

During this implementation i have found that the following attribute is added in the msdn before the WndProc method,
`[SecurityPermission( SecurityAction.LinkDemand, UnmanagedCode=true )]`

Now my question is what is the use of this attribute? and also is that mandatory to add this attribute for my override method. or we can skip this.

Please provide me the suggestion for this. 
Note: I have created the project in the .Net Framework 4.0

Comment: Well, I have overrided the `WndProc` method in one of my custom controls without that attribute and worked just fine. Search about when to use such attribute to see in which contexts it may be used.

Comment: I have searched about this attribute but, I could not found the clear vision about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding .NET's "SecurityAction" parameter for permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353968/understanding-nets-securityaction-parameter-for-permissions)